# When is $z = (-1)^k$ real for $0<k<1$?

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers

I was looking at the function $y = x^{0+k}$ on Desmos and noticed for certain values the graph would be reflected about the y-axis. Then let $x = -1$ and tried finding when it would lead to real values.
I tried plugging in values. Some obvious ones would be when $k = \frac{1}{2}$, $z$ wouldn't be real (also for $\frac{n}{2}$). If $k = \sqrt{2}$ then $z$ would also be complex. I tried using de Moivre's theorem but it just leads to trivial solutions. If it's too general of a question, perhaps change the question to only include rational inputs.

Comment: Please, use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) to type the math in your questions. Consider also that many users in this site won't even read your question if it's not properly formatted, let alone help you.

Comment: For real $t$, $(-1)^t$ is real if and only if $t\in\Bbb Z$.

Comment: @jjagmath unfortunately a lot of calculators try to allow for exceptions like $ (-1)^{1/3} = -1 $.  So then you get people on the internet like this, who think calculators arbitrate mathematical truth and therefore consider this a "discovery" rather than an observation of the behavior of a piece of software.  Very tiresome.

Comment: If and only if $k$ is a rational number with an odd denominator in reduced form?

Comment: How does formatting work? Is there an easier way to get symbols to show properly? I don't mind typing in symbols into something and copying the code.

Comment: @user624dash8 in case it matters, I place the blame on programmers who don't understand why it's inappropriate to define an everywhere-discontinuous function in an environment where inputs are floating point numbers.  You're just a victim of their bad decisions.  Do not trust calculators' take on exponents with negative base.

Comment: @GeoffreyTrang Ah, that makes sense. Since odd mutliples of \pi are zero and therefore the number has no imaginary part.
(still don't understand formatting).

Comment: @user624dash8 When I asked you to format properly the math in your question I share a link where you'll find how to do it.

Comment: @user624dash8 It makes sense because odd multiples of $\pi$ are $0$? The even multiples of $\pi$ are also $0$ (I'm assuming that you mean the $\sin$ function at those points). So that's doesn't make sense.

Comment: @JakeMirra I'm confused about you issue with calculators displaying these answers. In what context is it not true that $(-1)^{1/3}=-1$? Why don't these commands work (you need the $)

Comment: In the context of complex numbers, where (the principal value of) $z^w$ is defined as $e^{w\log z}$ where the principal branch of $\log$ is used.

Comment: @jjagmath Yep, you're right. Now I'm back to square one. But it does seem true that $(-1)^{1/2n+1}$ is real. So why is it true?

Comment: See [cube root of unity](https://unacademy.com/content/cbse-class-11/study-material/mathematics/cube-root-of-unity/#:~:text=The%20three%20roots%20of%20the,together%20yields%20the%20answer%20unity.)

Comment: As a more general case, you could try using the definition $z^c = \exp(c \log z)$ for any $z,c \in \mathbb{C}$ and use the definition $\log z = \ln|z| + i \arg z$ to observe what values of $k$ result in $(-1)^k \in \mathbb{R}$. Can you continue?

Comment: @Accelerator The entire issue comes from the fact that $\arg$ itself is not unambiguously defined. So, it is misleading to say what you said and nothing more; *how do you define $\arg$*?

Comment: @FShrike I realize my suggestion is ambiguous. l was just throwing out the two definitions as an idea.